# Trying To delete Files After unzipping python Zipfile

Tags: python, unzip

So there are quite a few posts about this and I have tried all the recommended solutions but none of them seem to work. I am trying to delete a zip archive after I unzip it.

I have tried `os.remove`, `os.unlink` using a `with` statement everything!  but I keep getting

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:
```

Many thanks in advance

```
def Unzip(f, password, foldername):
    '''
    This function unzips a file, based on parameters, 
    it will create folders and will overwrite files with the same 
    name if needed.
    '''

    if foldername != '':
        outpath = os.path.dirname(f) + '\\'+ foldername
        if not os.path.exists(outpath):
            os.mkdir(outpath)
    else:
        outpath = os.path.dirname(f)
        if not os.path.exists(outpath):
            os.mkdir(outpath)

    if password == '':
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
        z.extractall(outpath)
        z.close()
        os.unlink(f)

    else:
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
        z.extractall(outpath, None, password)
        z.close()
        os.unlink(f)
```

UPDATE so I changed the code around and this works:

```
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
    z.extractall(outpath)
    z.close()
    del z
    os.unlink(f)
```

Comment: you should add the delete part of your code

Comment: Can you delete the file "manually" from outside python?

Comment: Python uses boolean-coercion, so your code can be simplified by doing `if foldername:`  or `if not password`. Also, use `os.path.join` instead of manually stitching together strings.

Comment: What happens if you (after hopefully unifying your two codepaths by placing `z.close()` and `os.unlink` behind the `if password...`) place a `del z` before the unlink?

Comment: I can delete the files in windows, and ill try using the del z

Comment: YES the del z thing works

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a bug ([issue 16183](https://bugs.python.org/issue16183)), which is now fixed in the latest versions of Python 2 and 3. But as a workaround for earlier versions, pass a in file-object rather than a path:

```
with open(f, 'rb') as fileobj:
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(fileobj)
    z.extractall(outpath)
    z.close()
os.remove(f)
```

Comment: If i run in the debugger I get this to work but when i run the script I still get an error